# Drawing circle, OpenGL style

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graphics, embedded

I have a 13 x 13 array of pixels, and I am using a function to draw a circle onto them. (The screen is 13 * 13, which may seem strange, but its an array of LED's so that explains it.)

```
unsigned char matrix[13][13];
const unsigned char ON = 0x01;
const unsigned char OFF = 0x00;
```

Here is the first implementation I thought up. (It's inefficient, which is a particular problem as this is an embedded systems project, 80 MHz processor.)

```
// Draw a circle
// mode is 'ON' or 'OFF'
inline void drawCircle(float rad, unsigned char mode)
{
    for(int ix = 0; ix < 13; ++ ix)
    {
        for(int jx = 0; jx < 13; ++ jx)
        {
            float r; // Radial
            float s; // Angular ("theta")
            matrix_to_polar(ix, jx, &r, &s); // Converts polar coordinates
                                             // specified by r and s, where
                                             // s is the angle, to index coordinates
                                             // specified by ix and jx.
                                             // This function just converts to
                                             // cartesian and then translates by 6.0.
            if(r < rad)
            {
                matrix[ix][jx] = mode; // Turn pixel in matrix 'ON' or 'OFF'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that's clear. It's pretty simple, but then I programmed it so I know how it's supposed to work. If you'd like more info / explanation then I can add some more code / comments.

It can be considered that drawing several circles, eg 4 to 6, is very slow... Hence I'm asking for advice on a more efficient algorithm to draw the circles.

EDIT: Managed to double the performance by making the following modification:

The function calling the drawing used to look like this:

```
for(;;)
{
    clearAll(); // Clear matrix

    for(int ix = 0; ix < 6; ++ ix)
    {
        rad[ix] += rad_incr_step;
        drawRing(rad[ix], rad[ix] - rad_width);
    }

    if(rad[5] >= 7.0)
    {
        for(int ix = 0; ix < 6; ++ ix)
        {
            rad[ix] = rad_space_step * (float)(-ix);
        }

    }

    writeAll(); // Write 
}
```

I added the following check:

```
if(rad[ix] - rad_width < 7.0)
    drawRing(rad[ix], rad[ix] - rad_width);
```

This increased the performance by a factor of about 2, but ideally I'd like to make the circle drawing more efficient to increase it further. This checks to see if the ring is completely outside of the screen.

EDIT 2: Similarly adding the reverse check increased performance further.

```
if(rad[ix] >= 0.0)
    drawRing(rad[ix], rad[ix] - rad_width);
```

Performance is now pretty good, but again I have made no modifications to the actual drawing code of the circles and this is what I was intending to focus on with this question.

Edit 3: Matrix to polar:

```
inline void matrix_to_polar(int i, int j, float* r, float* s)
{
    float x, y;
    matrix_to_cartesian(i, j, &x, &y);
    calcPolar(x, y, r, s);
}

inline void matrix_to_cartesian(int i, int j, float* x, float* y)
{
    *x = getX(i);
    *y = getY(j);  
}

inline void calcPolar(float x, float y, float* r, float* s)
{
    *r = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    *s = atan2(y, x);
}

inline float getX(int xc)
{
    return (float(xc) - 6.0);
}

inline float getY(int yc)
{
    return (float(yc) - 6.0); 
}
```

In response to Clifford that's actually a lot of function calls if they are not inlined.

Edit 4: drawRing just draws 2 circles, firstly an outer circle with mode ON and then an inner circle with mode OFF. I am fairly confident that there is a more efficient method of drawing such a shape too, but that distracts from the question.

Comment: Take a look at the [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm), which doesn't require any trigonometry.

Comment: Is there enough memory to cache the point sets? That's probably easier to implement than Bresenham circle.

Comment: Although there are other methods, here the most processor intensive part is probably matrix_to_polar() and you have omitted that.

Comment: Using floating point as also worth avoiding.

Comment: @Clifford The implementation of matrix_to_polar is like 2 lines of "inlined" code however I cannot guarantee that the compiler inlined it. I will add those lines.

Comment: @Clifford Actually that's a lot of function calls in fairness. I will try speed it up tomorrow.

Comment: If you don't have an FPU (which seems unlikely on an 80MHz device), it is not so much the number of function calls but the number of floating-point operations that you should be concerned about.  Especially as the standard library functions are defined for double. (C++ has overloads, but they may only be implemented using casts rather than type optimised).

Comment: The code fragments seem contradictory - is it `drawCircle` or `drawRing` you are asking about?

Comment: Calculating the angle is a complete waste, and you can avoid the square root by simply squaring the inequality (inside the circle iff `(x-6)*(x-6) + (y-6)*(y-6) < r*r`).  Voila, no more floating-point.

Comment: Even better, test (x*x + y*y < r*r) in the range 0...6 and then draw (6+x,6+y), (6-x, 6+y), (6+x,6-y), and (6-x,6-y) all from a single test.

Comment: Can you declare your variable float r; float s; outside your for loop? and is it possible to reuse the same variables if you do so? If you can declare them outside the for loop, then that will save you two lines of code for each iteration on your for loop. Is it also possible to do loop unrolling on your matrix?

Comment: I would condense the three functions: matrix_to_polar(), matrix_to_cartesian(), calcPolar(), getX(int xc) and getY(int yc) into one or two functions. There is a lot of reference and pointers that should be reference once or twice and then used for the entire code, rather than having the CPU to look up for these pointers over and over again for each function you define. You can also multiply X*X for your calcPolar() function, only once for every 13 calls to the inner loop. Rather than computing it continuously and repeatedly.

Comment: There is no need to use any `float` to solve this problem, nor any calls to `sqrt()`.  Check comments by Ben Voigt and @David Eisenstat

Comment: There's some pretty neat stuff there thanks to all contributors, I am making changes now.

Comment: @BenVoigt : It seems that you have a great answer, but this is the comment section - please post an answer.  Other wise I might steal the idea an take the credit! ;-)

Comment: @Clifford: Looks like Reto already has an answer using the same approach.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a lot of calculations that aren't really needed. For example, you're calculating the angle of the polar coordinates, but never use it. The square root can also easily be avoided by comparing the square of the values.

Without doing anything fancy, something like this should be a good start:

```
int intRad = (int)rad;
int intRadSqr = (int)(rad * rad);

for (int ix = 0; ix <= intRad; ++ix)
{
    for (int jx = 0; jx <= intRad; ++jx)
    {
        if (ix * ix + jx * jx <= radSqr)
        {
            matrix[6 - ix][6 - jx] = mode;
            matrix[6 - ix][6 + jx] = mode;
            matrix[6 + ix][6 - jx] = mode;
            matrix[6 + ix][6 + jx] = mode;
        }
    }
}
```

This does all the math in integer format, and takes advantage of the circle symmetry.

Variation of the above, based on feedback in the comments:

```
int intRad = (int)rad;
int intRadSqr = (int)(rad * rad);

for (int ix = 0; ix <= intRad; ++ix)
{
    for (int jx = 0; ix * ix + jx * jx <= radSqr; ++jx)
    {
        matrix[6 - ix][6 - jx] = mode;
        matrix[6 - ix][6 + jx] = mode;
        matrix[6 + ix][6 - jx] = mode;
        matrix[6 + ix][6 + jx] = mode;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but with 2 additional modifications: Firstly I prefer `matrix[-ix + 6][+jx + 6]` as it seems clearer to me, the fact that 6 is added each time is to move the circle's position on the screen. Secondly I added an `else { break; }` as there is no point checking the y index values once one had been found outside the circle as all subsequent points will also be outside the circle.

Comment: That's a good idea to terminate the loop early. I added a second version doing that.

Comment: That's an even better method of doing it imo, although some may argue that it has been made slightly more difficult to read and that presumably a decent compiler would perform such an optimization? Although I am not sure about that and how good the average compiler on an embedded platform would be. (I am using the MPIDE from Digilent, with a Chipkit Max32)

Answer (score 1):

Don't underestimate the cost of even basic arithmetic using floating point on a processor with no FPU. It seems unlikely that floating point is necessary, but the details of its use are hidden in your `matrix_to_polar()` implementation.

Your current implementation considers *every* pixel as a candidate - that is also unnecessary.

Using the equation *y = cy ± √[rad<sup>2</sup> - (x-cx)<sup>2</sup>]* where cx, cy is the centre (7, 7 in this case), and a suitable integer square root implementation, the circle can be drawn thus:

```
void drawCircle( int rad, unsigned char mode )
{
    int r2 = rad * rad ;
    for( int x = 7 - rad; x <= 7 + rad; x++ )
    {
        int dx = x - 7 ;
        int dy = isqrt( r2 - dx * dx ) ;

        matrix[x][7 - dy] = mode ;
        matrix[x][7 + dy] = mode ;
    }
}
```

In my test I used the `isqrt()` below based on code from [here](http://www.finesse.demon.co.uk/steven/sqrt.html), but given that the maximum r<sup>2</sup> necessary is 169 (13<sup>2</sup>, you could implement a 16 or even 8 bit optimised version if necessary.  If your processor is 32 bit, this is probably fine.

```
uint32_t isqrt(uint32_t n)
{
   uint32_t root = 0, bit, trial;
   bit = (n >= 0x10000) ? 1<<30 : 1<<14;
   do
   {
      trial = root+bit;
      if (n >= trial)
      {
         n -= trial;
         root = trial+bit;
      }
      root >>= 1;
      bit >>= 2;
   } while (bit);

   return root;
}
```

All that said, on such a low resolution device, you will probably get better quality circles and faster performance by hand generating bitmap lookup tables for each radius required.  If memory is an issue, then a single circle needs only 7 bytes to describe a 7 x 7 quadrant that you can reflect to all three quadrants, or for greater performance you could use 7 x 16 bit words to describe a semi-circle (since reversing bit order is more expensive than reversing array access - unless you are using an ARM Cortex-M with bit-banding).  Using semi-circle look-ups, 13 circles would need 13 x 7 x 2 bytes (182 bytes), quadrant look-ups would be 7 x 8 x 13 (91 bytes) - you may find that is fewer bytes that the code space required to calculate the circles.

Comment: Looking at your original code again, it seems that you are drawing a *filled circle*.  That is not what my code does - it draws a circle.  I'll let it stand pending requirements clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, I didn't really consider the lack of floating point processor. The answer to this is that the chip I am using does not have a floating point unit.

Comment: @user3728501 The use of floating point will be your biggest performance killer in all of this.  You should always aim to avoid it in embedded systems with no FPU.  Even with an FPU you need to be careful as many Real-time Operating Systems (RTOS) do not automatically preserve FPU registers in context switches; this may also effect systems that use FPU emulation on non-FPU targets.

Answer (score 0):

For a slow embedded device with only a 13x13 element display, you should really just make a look-up table.  For example:

```
struct ComputedCircle
{
    float rMax;
    char col[13][2];
};
```

Where the draw routine uses `rMax` to determine which LUT element to use.  For example, if you have 2 elements with one rMax = 1.4f, the other = 1.7f, then any radius between 1.4f and 1.7f will use that entry.

The column elements would specify zero, one, or two line segments per row, which can be encoded in the lower and upper 4 bits of each char.  -1 can be used as a sentinel value for nothing-at-this-row.  It is up to you how many look-up table entries to use, but with a 13x13 grid you should be able to encode every possible outcome of pixels with well under 100 entries, and a reasonable approximation using only 10 or so.  You can also trade off compression for draw speed as well, e.g. putting the col[13][2] matrix in a flat list and encoding the number of rows defined.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work, could you provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

I would accept MooseBoy's answer if only he explained the method he proposes better. Here's my take on the lookup table approach.

**Solve it with a lookup table**

The 13x13 display is quite small, and if you only need circles which are fully visible within this pixel count, you will get around with a quite small table. Even if you need larger circles, it should be still better than any algorithmic way if you need it to be fast (and have the ROM to store it).

**How to do it**

You basically need to define how each possible circle looks like on the 13x13 display. It is not sufficient to just produce snapshots for the 13x13 display, as it is likely you would like to plot the circles at arbitrary positions. My take for a table entry would look like this:

```
struct circle_entry_s{
    unsigned int diameter;
    unsigned int offset;
};
```

The entry would map a given diameter in pixels to offsets in a large byte table containing the shape of the circles. For example for diameter `9`, the byte sequence would look like this:

```
0x1CU, 0x00U, /* 000111000 */
0x63U, 0x00U, /* 011000110 */
0x41U, 0x00U, /* 010000010 */
0x80U, 0x80U, /* 100000001 */
0x80U, 0x80U, /* 100000001 */
0x80U, 0x80U, /* 100000001 */
0x41U, 0x00U, /* 010000010 */
0x63U, 0x00U, /* 011000110 */
0x1CU, 0x00U, /* 000111000 */
```

The diameter specifies how many bytes of the table belong to the circle: one row of pixels are generated from `(diameter + 7) >> 3` bytes, and the number of rows correspond to the diameter. The output code of these can be made quite fast, while the lookup table is sufficiently compact to get even larger than the 13x13 display circles defined in it if needed.

Note that defining circles this way for odd and even diameters may or may not appeal you when output by a centre location. The odd diameter circles will appear to have a centre in the "middle" of a pixel, while the even diameter circles will appear to have their centre on the "corner" of a pixel.

You may also find it nice later to refine the overall method so having multiple circles of different apparent sizes, but having the same pixel radius. Depends on what is your goal: if you want some kind of smooth animation, you may get there eventually.

Algorithmic solutions I think mostly will perform poorly here, since with this limited display surface really every pixel's state counts for the appearance.